# Eclipse IDE: Filter files by filename in Working Set

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Looking for a way to quickly search or filter files *by filename* for a particular working set.

There are a couple options that almost do it:

The built-in "Open Resource" dialog (cmd + shift + R on mac) has the right behavior, but searches the entire workspace, not just the working set.

[image]

I also found [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-common-navigator-filtered-viewer) that allows filename filtering with a really nice field right in the UI, but it doesn't have an option to limit the navigator view to a working set.

[image]

I used to use a really old plugin called "navigator with filter" that was like the one above but allowed a working set to be chosen.  I just upgraded to 2019-03 and unfortunately it no longer works.

Comment: The normal _File Search_ (Ctrl+H) can do this: leave the _Containing text_ field empty, enter only _File Name Patterns_ and choose as scope the working set.

Comment: Thanks!  That does work.  I was kind of hoping for something quicker.  I like that plugin because it has the field built right into the view

Comment: [InstaSearch](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) is quicker and can do it also: enter `file:product.jsp` and click the filter icon to the right of the field (or append `ws:MyWorkingSet` to the query).

Comment: Interesting.  I will check that out.  Thanks!

Comment: InstaSearch is for full text search but can also be used to find a text file by name. To find a file by name in a _Working Set_ the _Open Resource_ dialog can be used (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the *Open Resource*** dialog there is a menu in the upper right corner where **a *Working Set* can be selected**:

[image]

Comment: Ah! I totally missed that - it's barely visible with the theme I'm using https://imgur.com/a/Sr8Wq10